# React native: How to store object in asyncstorage

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

i want to store object in asyncstorage,then i want get different values that was stored in object.

```
storeToken(responseData){

    AsyncStorage.setItem(ACCESS_TOKEN, responseData, (err)=> {
      if(err){
        console.log("an error");
        throw err;
      }
      console.log("success");
    }).catch((err)=> {
        console.log("error is: " + err);
    });
  }
```

i have stored in this way .but while getting particular value i can able get only one value am not able to get more values from object.

Comment: the reactnative team did hard work to make a useful doc. Take look at it http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You must stringify your object.

```
AsyncStorage.setItem(ACCESS_TOKEN, JSON.stringify(responseData), (err)=> {
    if(err){
        console.log("an error");
        throw err;
    }
    console.log("success");
}).catch((err)=> {
    console.log("error is: " + err);
});
```

And when you read it, you should parse it.

```
try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN);
    if (value !== null) {
        // We have data!!
        console.log(JSON.parse(value));
    }
} catch (error) {
    // Error retrieving data
}
```